# Problem importing images using New Magento Import

Tags: magento, import

I am trying to import products using import/export in Enterprise version 1.10.
this import/export is same as what is included in 1.5.

My issue is when i import the file,images are not importing correctly.

I use "/imagename.jpg" in my image column.
i put all images in media/import folder.

what is strange is when i export the file , it show me the same image name in image column "/imagename.jpg" and there is no image showing in product->images in Admin.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Check the exported products file, it could be that there are directory paths in front of the image file name.

Comment: i already double checked it and it is showing same as what i enter in import csv, and there is no file or folder imported in media/catalog/product folder

Comment: I did an import with a similar situation where only about 30% of the images were imported properly. Hopefully someone will have an answer for us :)

Comment: If it's a one time import, check the following link, it could save your life... http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/quickly-associate-images-to-your-magento-products-without-using-dataflow/

Comment: same problem for me, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

First of all make sure that your import file has a prepending slash for image
“sku”,"image" 
“ABC123”,"/abc123.jpg"

Try to follow these steps:

1. list a sample product on your store.
2. export the csv sample (for this go to: system>import/export>Dataflow - profiles then select export all products)
3. open up and edit the csv, make sure you use OPENOFFICE calc - This will allow you to edit and save in UTF-8 format.
4. add the additional products line by line.
5. in the image field put this /myimage.jpg - that is forward slash and your image name
6. Ensure you place the product images in this folder: public_html/media/import
7. Now you need to import the csv (for this go to: system>import/export>Dataflow - profiles then select import all products, next you select “upload File”. You then need to select the file you just edited and upload it to the server.  Next, you will select “Run Profile”

Comment: @AndrewBarber The answer seems to adequately address the question

Comment: @NullUserException I happen to agree in this case. Perhaps the File2Cart people are slowly learning how to properly post answers that happen to include links to their website.

Comment: @NullUserException However, I'll note that the wording on the article link is "Also I have found this article..." I know it's possible this is a third-party posting the answer, but...

Answer (score 2):

One solution for your problem would be to place your images inside media/catalog/product/import instead of media/import

Seems Magento is now pulling the images from that dir, at least that worked for me.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried everything I found online, but nothing worked.  Final answer after a week of head-butting was this:
**filenames in the media/import folder were uppercase.  The ones in the csv file were lowercase**  Changed filenames in csv file to be lowercase and everything worked like a dream.